# vuejs axios GET with headers not working in safari

Tags: vue.js, axios, xmlhttprequest

I am making the following GET call which works perfectly on Chrome, but not on Safari:

```
methods: {
    fetchData: function() {
      var self = this;

      axios
        .get(MY_API_URL, {
          headers: {
            "X-Locale": self.locale, // self.locale = "en"
           // tried these too
           // "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
           // "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
           // "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
          }

        })
        .then(function(data) {
          let strings = data.data.data;
          console.log("strings: ", self.strings);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error", error);
        });
    }
},
async mounted() {
    await this.fetchData();
}
```

the errors Safari gives:

```
[Error] Request header field X-Locale is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load MY_API_URL due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Request header field X-Locale is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. (content, line 0)
```

Comment: What CORS headers is your API returning?

Comment: Also, which version of Safari are you using? Older versions don't support `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *`, which would explain the error you're seeing and also why it works in Chrome. Note that this is a response header, present on your API, not a request header the way your code comment implies.

Comment: @skirtle: `Response No response headers` and Safari v 12.1 but also Safari mobile v12

Comment: ios 13 safari (v13) works fine.

Comment: Use the Network tab of the Chrome developer tools to check the response headers, they should be effectively the same as you're getting in Safari. I'm pretty sure you'll find that the server is returning `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` on the preflight OPTIONS request, which won't work in older browsers. You'll need to change the server config to list the headers individually rather than using `*`.

Comment: @skirtle: you're right! in chrome i am getting this `access-control-allow-headers: *` together with a bunch of others on the Response Headers

Comment: @skirtle any hint on what the individual headers should be?

Comment: I suggest you do some background reading about CORS and specifically the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header. It would need to be something like `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Locale`.

Answer (score 2):

thanks to @skirtle I've arrived to this answer:

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` is not supported by Safari:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

this was more of a server-side solve.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
X-Locale,Content-Type,Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers
```